# Django. TemporaryUploadedFile

Tags: python-3.x, django

I upload a file through the form, check it, and only after checking it I want to add it to my database.

```
form = BookForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
file = form.files
path = file.get('book_file').temporary_file_path()
```

`in path - '/tmp/tmpbp4klqtw.upload.pdf'`

But as soon as I want to transfer this file from the temporary storage to some other folder, I get the following error:

```
path = os.replace(path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/tmp/tmpbp4klqtw.upload.pdf' -> '/home/oem/bla/bla'`

Can't understand why this file is not in reality? What can I do about it? Is it possible to set some special path for the "temporary file"?

UPD:

```
You should use path = os.replace(path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/name-of-file.pdf') – Willem Van Onsem
```

Comment: You should use `path = os.replace(path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/name-of-file.pdf')`

Comment: Woow! You right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`os.replace(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace) expects a filename as target if you specify a file as source, so you can move this to:

```
os.replace(path, f'{settings.MEDIA_ROOT}/name-of-file.pdf')
```

you can also make use of [**`shutil.move(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to specify the directory, this function will also return the filepath of the target file:

```
from shutil import move

target_file = move(path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```